# custom regex redirect in htaccess

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess

My old website structure had city urls organized by year, like so:

- http://www.mywebsite.com/2010/san-francisco-details.html,
- http://www.mywebsite.com/2011/san-francisco-details-1.html
- http://www.mywebsite.com/2012/san-francisco-details-1.html
- http://www.mywebsite.com/2013/san-francisco-details.html

.. I need all those redirected to this new url:

- http://www.mywebsite.com/cities/san_francisco_ca

I can get the folder right with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^2010/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ /cities/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^2011/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ /cities/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^2012/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ /cities/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteRule ^2013/(.+?)(-[0-9]+)?$ /cities/$1 [L,R=301]
```

but it ofcourse results in a 404 because the file names are not exactly identical.

The pattern here I see is to get the first two words of the OLD url (san-francisco), and provide the new URL manually, pseduo-code:

```
if found san-francisco redirect /cities/san_francisco_ca
if found honolulu redirect /cities/honolulu_hi
```

...but I'm not sure how to write a regex as complicated as that.

Comment: How many cities do you have? if it is a large number it will be easiest to first get all the redirects mapped to the city string.  If it is only 10 then you can just manually do it, and to write the regex we'll need to know all the cities you wrote about...normally i'd write some SQL queries then generate the regex from those results.

Comment: You've `san-francisco` in your URLs but you want redirect to `san_francisco_ca` notice `ca` part that isn't out there. how ever your regex matches whole `san-francisco-details.html`

Comment: @Nimbuz if you can give the 20 cities, and then we'll move to the regex you need.

Comment: @abc123 sure, these are the new city names: http://pastebin.com/0Yn4gcJC

Comment: @abc123 list of cities for 2012 as an example: http://pastebin.com/UqVTHcdx

Comment: @Nimbuz: If you have access to change Apache config then I will suggest using `RewriteMap` feature.

Comment: @anubhava no I don't its a shared hosting account.

Comment: I would suggest that you rewrite all old links to a single routing php file then that file does the processing and returns a `301` to the new URL, the upside is that you can dynamically add and remove cities and you wouldn't need to configure and restart/reload nginx every time you want to add/remove a city

Comment: @Nimbuz: I guess then you will need lots of rules. I don't know how you can write rule for each city. May be better to create a database table and do this redirection via PHP.

Comment: @MohammadAbuShady Aha, any direction on how to do that?

Comment: Does your app contain a single entry point? Or are they several PHP files depending on the URI's

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Redirect code for htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^201\d/(san)-(antonio).*\.html$ /cities/$1_$2_tx [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(phoenix).*\.html$ /cities/$1_az [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(honolulu).*\.html$ /cities/$1_hi [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(houston).*\.html$ /cities/$1_tx [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(dallas).*\.html$ /cities/$1_tx [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(washington).*\.html$ /cities/$1_dc [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(philadelphia).*\.html$ /cities/$1_pa [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(atlanta).*\.html$ /cities/$1_ga [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(rochester).*\.html$ /cities/$1_ga [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(minneapolis).*\.html$ /cities/$1_mn [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(chicago).*\.html$ /cities/$1_il [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(new)-(york).*\.html$ /cities/$1_$2_ny [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/nyc.*\.html$ /cities/new_york_ny [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(boston).*\.html$ /cities/$1_ma [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(seattle).*\.html$ /cities/$1_wa [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(denver).*\.html$ /cities/$1_co [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(san)-(francisco).*\.html$ /cities/$1_$2_ca [L,R=301,NC]
RewriteRule ^201\d/(st).?.(louis).*\.html$ /cities/$1_$2_mo [L,R=301,NC]
```

In there you'll see some of my special cases for you.

---

**Description**

The `NC` flag removes case sensitivity.

Let me know if you need more.

---

**The Other Side**

As some people have mentioned another way would be to have an include file that simply did these redirects for you rather than using the `htaccess` this would allow you to have a database of the cities and states and make the below not as unique.

Comment: WOW! Just had to add `$2_` for san-francisco but otherwise perfect!! Thanks heaps man!

Comment: @Nimbuz not a problem corrected the typo! Glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^2010/([a-z]*)-([a-z]*)-details(-[0-9])*.html$ /cities/$1_$2_ca [R=301,L]
```

OR:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^2010/([a-z]*)-([a-z]*)-([a-z]*)(-[0-9])*.html$ /cities/$1_$2_ca [R=301,L]
```

When you access 
http://www.mywebsite.com/2010/san-francisco-details.html
Or
http://www.mywebsite.com/2010/san-francisco-details-1.html

You will be redirected to 
http://www.mywebsite.com/cities/san_francisco_ca

I am not sure where the '_ca' part is in the original url, so I added it manually.

Comment: If i went to http://www.mywebsite.com/2010/---.html i'd also go to http://www.mywebsite.com/cities/__ca this isn't specific enough for this situation unfortunately.  if you changed the regex to `^2010/(san)-(francisco).*\.html$` then it would work for that 1 city case

Comment: exactly, this wouldn't work for all cities cause not all are in CA

Comment: Your comments are right, it doesn't suit cities that you don't want the '_ca' ending. Sorry, I am not from America and I am not familiar with America cities. If the post author could provide city list or other information, I may workout something better. Thanks. @abc123